# Python Pandas how to group columns by duplicated values in another

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'hour': pd.Series(['17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00']),
                   'url': pd.Series(['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4']),
                   'string': pd.Series(['my name', 'your name', 'my name', 'your name'])})

    hour   url     string
0  17:00  url1    my name
1  18:00  url2  your name
2  19:00  url3    my name
3  20:00  url4  your name
```

and I have to get some like this:

```
       string          hour               url
0     my name     '17:00','19:00'      url1, url3
1     your name   '18:00','20:00'      url2, url4
```

Is there a way to do this transform?

Comment: `df.groupby('string').agg(list)`?

Comment: `df.groupby('string').agg(', '.join).reset_index()`?

Comment: *"group by a column"* is called ***`groupby`***, and *"group/process duplicated values together"* is typically an ***`aggregate`***, in your case *"aggregate into a list"*. Please briefly skim the ["10 minutes to pandas" tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html) so you learn the important terms, it will help you phrase questions.